# Python MeanShift Memory Error

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis, scikit-learn

I'm running a clustering algorithm called `MeanShift()` in the `sklearn.cluster` module ([here are the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.html)). The object I'm dealing with has  310,057 points distributed in 3-dimensional space. The computer I'm running it on has a total of 128Gb of ram, so when I get the following error, I have a hard time believing that I'm actually using all of it.

```
[user@host ~]$ python meanshifttest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "meanshifttest.py", line 13, in <module>
    ms = MeanShift().fit(X)
  File "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/mean_shift_.py", line 280, in fit
    cluster_all=self.cluster_all)
  File "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/mean_shift_.py", line 99, in mean_shift
bandwidth = estimate_bandwidth(X)
  File "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/mean_shift_.py", line 45, in estimate_bandwidth
d, _ = nbrs.kneighbors(X, return_distance=True)
  File "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.py", line 313, in kneighbors
return_distance=return_distance)
  File "binary_tree.pxi", line 1313, in sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.BinaryTree.query (sklearn/neighbors/kd_tree.c:10007)
  File "binary_tree.pxi", line 595, in sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.NeighborsHeap.__init__ (sklearn/neighbors/kd_tree.c:4709)
MemoryError
```

The code I'm running looks like this:

```
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift
import asciitable
import numpy as np
import time

data = asciitable.read('./multidark_MDR1_FOFID85000000000_ParticlePos.csv',delimiter=',')
x = [data[i][2] for i in range(len(data))]
y = [data[i][3] for i in range(len(data))]
z = [data[i][4] for i in range(len(data))]
X = np.array(zip(x,y,z))

t0 = time.time()
ms = MeanShift().fit(X)
t1 = time.time()
print str(t1-t0) + " seconds."
labels = ms.labels_
print set(labels)
```

Would anybody have any ideas about what's happening? Unfortunately I can't switch clustering algorithms because this is the only one I've found which does a good job in addition to accepting no linking lengths/k number of clusters/a priori information.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:
I looked into the documentation a little more, and it says the following:

> > Scalability:
> >
> > Because this implementation uses a flat kernel and
> >     a Ball Tree to look up members of each kernel, the complexity will is
> >     to O(T*n*log(n)) in lower dimensions, with n the number of samples
> >     and T the number of points. In higher dimensions the complexity will
> >     tend towards O(T*n^2).
> >
> > Scalability can be boosted by using fewer seeds, for example by using
> >     a higher value of min_bin_freq in the get_bin_seeds function.
> >
> > Note that the estimate_bandwidth function is much less scalable than
> >     the mean shift algorithm and will be the bottleneck if it is used.

This seems to make some sense, because if you look at the error in detail it is complaining about estimate_bandwidth. Is this an indication that I'm simply using too many particles for the algorithm?

Comment: What does a memory monitor, such as `top` or `free`, shows you? (In `top`, sort by resident memory: press S then Q.)

Comment: Yea, so I've done that, and I'm only using 0.2% of the total memory (which is 128Gb). It also fails almost instantaneously - which indicates that it is something else. I don't see how it could use that much RAM so quickly.

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the size of the problem somehow? Is there a known case where everything works, and you can measure the amount of memory used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from the error message, I suspect it's trying to compute all pairwise distances between points, which means it needs 310057² floating point numbers or 716GB of RAM.

You can disable this behavior by giving an explicit `bandwidth` argument to the `MeanShift` constructor.

This is arguably a bug; consider filing a bug report for it. (The scikit-learn crew, which includes myself, have recently been working to get rid of these overly expensive distance computations in various places, but apparently no-one looked at meanshift.)

**EDIT**: the computations above were off by factor of 3, but the memory usage was indeed quadratic. I just fixed this in the dev version of scikit-learn.

Comment: Thanks so much for the post. Is it true that it would actually take that amount of RAM for me to run this algorithm? I've done this with ~30,000 particles and I could have sworn that it worked on a different work computer with 4GB of RAM. I'll file the bug with sklearn.

Comment: @astromax: this computation, as currently implemented, creates an array of n² 64-bit floating point numbers. 30k² = 9e8, times 8 makes 6.7GB, so that may be doable, but quadratic space grows *fast*.

Comment: Gotcha. Are there non- n-squared methods which will make their way into the code?

Comment: @astromax: scikit-learn is a "doocracy", i.e. bugs get fixed fastest if users submit patches. Btw., I just looked at the code a little longer and it seems to be not exactly n², but certainly more than linear.

Comment: How can I get the new code? Do I have to have the developer version?

Comment: I should also add taht I'm using Anaconda python. I can update packages which are included there by easily. My question is once this bug has been fixed (thanks by the way!), how do I pull changes?

Comment: @astromax: I don't use Anaconda myself, but I think you'll have to wait for the next release (in a few weeks) and its adoption by Anaconda (no control over that).